# Delete blank rows using Macro, after Row x

Tags: excel, vba

I've found this Macro on another post:

```
Sub DelBlankRows()

Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Can this be modified so that it only deletes rows after row x (row 14 on the spreadsheet that I'm currently working on)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is fairly straightforward.

```
Rows(x & ":" & y).EntireRow.Delete
```

Just swap x and y for the rows you want.

As an aside, it is best to avoid selecting ranges unnecessarily as it only slows things down. Any time you select a range then do something with the selection, you can just perform that action directly on the range instead.

EDIT: Just re-read the question - so try this one:

```
Range("A14:A" & Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: To clarify, I should replace

Selection.EntireRow.Delete

with

Rows(x & ":" & y).EntireRow.Delete

?

At the moment that deletes all rows within the range, whether the cell in column A is blank or not. I need to only delete the row when the cell in column A is blank.

Comment: I'm guessing the edit solves the issue, could you please confirm which parts of the code I'm replacing?

Comment: For the benefit of anyone else reading this who's as inexperienced with VBA's as me the full macro is: Sub DelBlankRows()
Range("A14:A" & Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub

Comment: Just got back to see your comments, glad you sussed it out